# constraint xxxxxxx is not a foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

I'm importing millions of rows from different files.

One of those files throws an exception about a constraint:

> PG::InternalError: ERROR:  constraint 109531 is not a foreign key constraint (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

How can I find the constrain 109531?

I can't find it on pg_constraint ...

Where I should look?

### EDIT:

The error comes directly from PostgreSQL, Activerecord is passing it.

After adding a parent row manually using psql, now if I want to delete or update the row, I'm getting a new constrain error:

```
ERROR:  constraint 109529 is not a foreign key constraint
```

If I try to find the constrain:

```
select * FROM pg_constraint;
```

I can see lots of constraints with similar numbers:

```
107878,109309,109521
```

Only with

```
TRUNCATE table CASCADE;
```

the row has been deleted

Comment: There might not be a dbms constraint named "109531". That error message is coming from ActiveRecord, right? Can you import through PostgreSQL's `psql` client? Can you `grep` for 109531 in the files you're importing? (The message suggests that there's a SQL statement that's trying to do something with a foreign key by name. Would that surprise you? It would surprise me.)

Comment: ActiveRecord imports from a JSON with nested attributes, I could create the parent row, and when I try to delete it directly from pssql, I get this: ERROR:  constraint 109527 is not a foreign key constraint (I can't find it on pg_constraint also)

Comment: Did you create a row using psql? If not, are you creating a row with "child" rows? (The name of the constraint in your comment is different than the name in your question.)

Comment: As your proposal, I created a parent row (without child) directly from psql. After creating manually, if I want to delete/update, PostgreSQL issues a different constraint error, that's why it's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after deleting ALL constraints and recreating them (with methods as there are more than 200 constraints), everything works perfect ...

I've used this [link](http://blog.hagander.net/archives/131-Automatically-dropping-and-creating-constraints.html) for the automated generated/removed constraints